# How to deploy private tor network on the Internet

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, private

Is that possible to deploy my own private tor network on the Internet (not on the LAN)? I got five alicloud servers. 2 for directory authorities and 3 for tor relay servers. Here is my `torrc` file:

```
Nickname Atom
TestingTorNetwork 0
DataDirectory /usr/local/var/lib/tor
RunAsDaemon 1
ConnLimit 60
ShutdownWaitLength 0
PidFile /usr/local/var/lib/tor/pid

Log info file /usr/local/var/log/tor/info.log
Log debug file /usr/local/var/log/tor/debug.log
ProtocolWarnings 1
SafeLogging 0
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
AssumeReachable 0

SocksPort 0
ORPort 443
Address XXX.XXX.XXX.XX(public IP)
OutboundBindAddress XXX.XXX.XXX.XX(public IP)
DirPort 80


ExitPolicy accept *:*
ExitRelay 1
IPv6Exit 0
AuthoritativeDirectory 1
V3AuthoritativeDirectory 1
```

Tor relay servers got almost the same configuration(Plus `PublishServerDescriptor 1 AssumeReachable 0`). Then I can barely built circuit. Only one hop internal circuit built successfully. From log on one of the relay server, I can see relay server didn't generate and upload its own descriptors to authorities. Is there something wrong with my `torrc`? How can I make my own tor works? Any advice will be warmly welcome! Thanks!

Comment: by the way, I've replaced directory authorities fingerprints and address ---which hardcode in config.c---with my directory authorities fingerprints and address . So I didn't write it in my torrc

Comment: There was discussion of this exact question by Tom Ritter on the Tor-talk or Tor-dev mailing list. There are some other issues that need to be addressed before making. I'm not putting it in as the answer because I can't find it in the archive. This is a good start: https://ritter.vg/blog-run_your_own_tor_network.html

Comment: @robbie I have a collaboration offer - I'm making my research in hybridising darknets to help each other. Currently I'm working with Tor and I2P. If you're interested - contact me.